# create a new array from an existing array at specific indexes

Tags: javascript

```
const array = ["john", "mark", "sally", "adam", "rick"]

const newArray = //the index values between array[0] and array[2]
//newArray= ["john", "mark", "sally"]
```

How would I go on getting that value? is there a specific function for method for it?
Alternativaly, can I convert the specified index values to a string? eg:

```
const newString = //the index values between array[0] and array[2]
//newString= "johnmarksally"
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? If you are struck on some particular thing then please share the relevant code so that we can tell you where you went wrong, or maybe what should be more efficient approach. SO is not a code writing service. Also: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I realize my question wasn't welcomed, I tend to research my problems before asking on stackOverflow but I couldn't find a direct source to this problem I had. I was building a filter algorithm for an assignment and @MrCodingB helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const array = ["john", "mark", "sally", "adam", "rick"]

const newArray = array.slice(0, 3);
console.log(newArray);

const newString = newArray.join('');
console.log(newString);
```